# "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" for string format dd/MM/yyyyTHH:mm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I am taking in input using a Html.TextBoxFor declared as `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { type = "datetime-local", @class = "form-control", @style = "height:34px;width:230px" })` there are two of these both of which pass their values through AJAX to a C# controller function which does the following

`DateTime ResourceStart = DateTime.ParseExact(resource_start, "dd/MM/yyyyTHH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

`DateTime ResourceDue = DateTime.ParseExact(resource_due, "dd/MM/yyyyTHH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

The values of `resource_start` and `resource_due` are "2016-12-02T09:30" and "2016-12-12T12:50" respectively.

The follwing is the exception detail when the program crashes.

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
       at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
       at ITPortal.Areas.ITWorkstream.Controllers.WorkstreamController.CreateResource(Int32 task_id, String resource_start, String resource_due) in c:\Work\ITPortal\ITPortal-DEV\ITPortal\Areas\ITWorkstream\Controllers\WorkstreamController.cs:line 247
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException:
```

I think my problem lies in the format that I have declared for my string in the ParseExact function, can anyone tell me which format to use instad?

Comment: have you tried with "/" instead of "-" in your values?

Comment: `/` is not the same as `-` (but why not make your parameters `DateTime` instead of `string` so they will be correctly bound)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format strings `"dd/MM/yyyyTHH:mm"` do not match your input format `2016-12-02T09:30`: the format is day-first with slashes, while the input is year-first with dashes.

You should either change your input to `02/12/2016T09:30`, or change your format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(resource_due, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```